# How to download files uploaded in a webform through views module?

Tags: views, 7, webforms, files

I have something like this in registration form and I am using webform module.

[image]

I need to show the uploaded file link in reports (using views module) When they click they should be able to download that file.

Comment: Have you considered Views data export?

Comment: yes I did consider that as well. But not necessary..atleast if it shows the uploaded file name, that would be great.